# Nested forms in Devise (Rails 3.2) - Not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-forms

I have setup an app using the Devise gem to login (User model). Within the sign up view, ive included a simple_fields_for form which includes the attributes from the Student model.

Everything displays correctly in the view, but when the submit button is clicked the nested record is not created.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role,    :student_attributes
# attr_accessible :title, :body

has_one :student, :inverse_of => :user, :autosave => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :student

end
```

Student model

```
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course, :email, :fname, :lname, :student_num, :university, :year

  set_primary_key :student_num

  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :student, :autosave => true

  has_many :attendances
  has_many :teaching_sessions, through: :attendances

  has_many :completed_outcomes

  validates :student_num, presence: true
  validates :fname, presence: true
  validates :lname, presence: true
  validates :university, presence: true
  validates :course, presence: true
  validates :year, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true


  def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Student.create! row.to_hash
end
  end

  def full_name
    "#{fname} #{lname}"
  end

end
```

Devise Registration Form

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<h3>Login Details</h3>

<div class="form-inputs">

  <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  <%= f.select :role, ["Student","Teacher","Admin"], :required => true %>
</div>

<h3>Profile</h3>

<div id = "student_fields">
  <%= simple_fields_for :student do |s| %>
    <%= s.input :student_num %>
    <%= s.input :fname %>
    <%= s.input :lname %>
    <%= s.input :university %>
    <%= s.input :course %>
    <%= s.input :year %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<br />

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
</div>

<% end %>

<br />

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Custom Devise Controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.build_student
    respond_with resource
  end

  def create
super
  end

  def update
super
  end

end
```

Ive read through pretty much every post on here, and still cannot find a way to get the nested model to save when clicking the submit button. The user record is created without problem, but the student details do not save. If anyone has any advice I would be hugely grateful. Im sure its something very simple that I'm missing but Ive been wrestling with this all day!

Best Wishes,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with an "f." on the front of your simple_fields_for?

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :student do |s| %>
```

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for

Comment: Thats frickin awesome thanks!

I had originally tried it with the f.simple_fields_for, but this was within a partial instead, and returned an error saying "f" not found or some such.

Thank you very much indeed! I knew it would be something simple.

Cheers!

Mike

Comment: If you want to pass "f" to a partial that contains the `simple_fields_for` input fields, you can call `<%= render partial: 'yourpartialhere', locals: { f: f } %>` from the main view.